# why are wekan calls to mongodb unable to connect?

Tags: mongodb, manjaro

I recently installed Manjaro and followed this tutorial: https://snapcraft.io/install/wekan/manjaro to install wekan. Everything went slicker than snot. I registered an account no issues, open the weken webgui at port 8080 without issue, create new lists and cards fine, but when I go to open the cards I create the connection to 127.0.0.1 is refused. Although it doesn't specify a port, I assume this is a call to the mongodb at the default port 27017, but I also opened up 28017 in the firewall.

Although mongo definitely seems to have been installed since I can see it is running, I can't `find` a mongod*.conf file on the system to verify the default ports.

This is the first time I used “snap” to install anything, and because it all went so seamlessly I have no clue where to start looking to find the issue. Is there a utility in snap where I can find out exactly what was installed to support wekan (webserver, database, etc.) that I can start checking into as potentials sources of issue. Thks.